# Monodevelop web application not running

Tags: 11.10, monodevelop

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, have installed Monodevelop-2.8.5, on the first run, it said the xsp2 server was missing, I installed that.

Now, the application builds successfully, but, when I run my application, it just opens google chrome (and not my application). What is the problem?

The application output is,

```
Registering application:
    Host:          any
    Port:          any
    Virtual path:  /
    Physical path: /home/tarun/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/
xsp2
Listening on address: 127.0.0.1
Root directory: /home/tarun/MyWebsite/MyWebsite
Listening on port: 8080 (non-secure)
```

When I try to open, 127.0.0.1:8080 on chrome, I get the following error :

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080

But, 127.0.0.1 works just fine.

Comment: Could you please tell how you run the application? What happens if you try to open the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080` with another browser while the application is running? Do you have a firewall running on your host?

Comment: Does the example asp.net application work? To test this, `cd` to `usr/share/asp.net2-demos/` and run the `#xsp` command.

Comment: @tohuwawohu there is `no such file or directory`

and I run the application in mono by `ctrl+f5`

Comment: @tohuwawohu so when I run the application only chrome opens and not my applicaiton, now while the application is running and I open another tab and enter `127.0.0.1:8080` it navigates to `Default.aspx` of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like to be a chrome-related problem, so you should set any other browser as default browser on your system. Maybe monodevelop has a config option regarding the web browser to start, so you should check monodevelop's config options too.

Comment: how in the world do you know all this?

Comment: @Tarun: it's all the same with those IDEs :-)